# Fingerprint Lock doesn't work in Ubuntu 21.04

Tags: 21.04

I installed Ubuntu 21.04 as a fresh O.S in my laptop MSI Prestige 15 A10SC and it comes with the fingerprint support but in my settings panel no fingerprint options are shown, I am also attaching the screenshot of my settings panel, Hope so it can be solved.

[image]

Comment: There is currently [no known driver for that fingerprint reader](https://linux-hardware.org/index.php?probe=6c6091dbad). Hopefully this is something that will be resolved in the near future.

Comment: Thanks for the info @matigo